# Remove CSS3 text-shadows and box-shadows from IE

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, css

I've looked high and low and it seems like an easy enough question.

I am using CSS3 shadows (box and text) and it really destroys any readability in IE, so I want to just remove all shadows in this style sheet. I have a conditional style sheet set up for IE8 and below.

I've tried this:

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent; 
filter: dropshadow(color=transparent, offx=0, offy=0);
```

But to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ie8 doesn't understand what text-shadow is, so overriding it is pointless. your readability issues could stem from any number of things: font-stack, cleartype, etc. without more info, pretty hard to tell.

Comment: I have commented out anything I thought would be the problem and it stems directly from this: `filter: dropshadow(color=#fff, offx=0, offy=1);`

Comment: oh, you're using filters to apply the shadows. um...take your filters out and put them in a style sheet for versions of ie greater than 8

Comment: Oh okay, all of my googling got me to another filter that I thought applied only to under IE9, but it looks like even IE9 has no shadow support (typical...)

Comment: @jordaninternets - They removed the `filter` style in IE9, so they could support CSS3 properly. However there were a few things that could be done previously with `filter` that aren't in IE9's new CSS features, so some functionality has been lost. Gradients is one, and from your comment here it looks like text shadow might be another. (but it's worth it to be rid of that hateful `filter` style!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
filter: glow(color=black,strength=1);  
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=135,strength=1,color=#640800);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(color=#640800,strength=2);
```